# Error SQL: ORA-00907: "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have `TABLE_A (user, book, msdin)`;
and `TABLE_B (car_id, user, book, msdin)`;

I am trying to make this insert

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (car_id, user, book, msdin)
values 
(11, (select user, book, msdin from TABLE_A));
```

but I got this error: `ORA-00907:  "missing right parenthesis"`, but the number of right / left parenthesis is the same

Comment: what is that 11 value?

Comment: You want to insert into 4 columns, but specify 1 + 4 values.

Comment: You are inserting more than 4 values

Comment: `INSERT INTO TABLE_B (car_id, user, book, msdin)
select 11, ... from TABLE_A;` However, you'll probably get a primary key duplicate here (if the select returns more than one row.)

Comment: there was an error. Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your no.of columns in insert does not matches the no.of columns in values field.
Try This..

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (car_id, user, book, msdin)
select 11, user, book, msdin from TABLE_A ;
```

Comment: `TABLE_A` does not have a `car_id` column - this should be the number literal `11`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need the `INSERT SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (car_id, user, book, msdin)
select 11, user, book, msdin from TABLE_A;
```

The number of values and their data types returned by `SELECT` has to correspond to the attributes of the table behind `INSERT`. It is not possible to use subselect behind `VALUES` in `INSERT` as you try it.

Answer (score -2):

If your TABLE_A only has 1 record, then you will need to do the following -

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (car_id, user, book, msdin)
values 
    (11, 
     (select  user from TABLE_A),
     (select book from TABLE_A),
     (select msdin from TABLE_A),
);
```

Comment: @Dear Downvoters - It would be nice, if you could add a comment as well. As per me, the above answer will work for sure.

Comment: that is what my first line in the answer says, if your `TABLE_A` has only  1 record.